# How to check if the given time is in between the timelimit

Tags: java, date, timestamp

Below are the list of transactions, I need to get the count of transactions done for every 15 mins, 00:01 to 00:15, 00:16 to 00:30 , 00:31 to 00:45 ...23:45(till end of the day) and incase if there is no transaction done at that particular time need to populate 0.00,

Sample data:

```
124385 20191029001650
124385 20191029002050
124385 20191029102050
124391 20191029135007
124391 20191029135507 
124392 20191029144229
```

expected output should be `0.00,2,0.00,0.00,0.00 ....`

we need to send the data like at 00:15 to 00:30 "2" transaction has been done and from 10:16 to 10:30 "1" transaction.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest you to look into Java Time API and specifically the class Instant. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html. It provides convenient method to check if one timestamp is before or after or between other timestamps.

Comment: Is your example list correct? You have multiples of the txn id values, and duplicate pairs of txn & timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Define an `event` class with two member fields: an `Long` integer object for the transaction number, and an `LocalDateTime for the date-time value (or`Instant` if you know the intended time zone or offset-from-UTC).

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

final public class Event implements Comparable < Event >
{
    // -------|  Members  |-----------------------------------
    final private Integer transactionId;
    final private LocalDateTime when;

    // -------|  Constructors  |-----------------------------------
    public Event ( Integer transactionId , LocalDateTime when )
    {
        this.transactionId = Objects.requireNonNull( transactionId );
        this.when = Objects.requireNonNull( when );
    }

    // -------|  Accessors  |-----------------------------------
    // Immutable, read-only. So getters only, no setters.
    public Integer getTransactionId ( )
    {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getWhen ( )
    {
        return when;
    }

    // -------|  Object  |-----------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Event event = ( Event ) o;
        return getTransactionId().equals( event.getTransactionId() ) &&
                getWhen().equals( event.getWhen() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getTransactionId() , getWhen() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Event{ " +
                "transactionId=" + transactionId +
                " | when=" + when +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Parse your incoming data.

For the ID number, use `Integer` class to parse.

```
Integer transactionId = Integer.valueOf( input ) ;
```

For the date-time, define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
```

Parse each string.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Sort the objects by each `LocalDateTime`. Either implement `Comparable` or make a `Comparator` object. Both have been covered many many times in Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

```
// --------|  Comparator  |-----------------------
/**
 * Comparator by `when`
 */
public static Comparator <Event> WhenComparator = new Comparator<Event>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        return e1.getWhen().compareTo( e2.getWhen() );
    }
};
```

Start with the first object. Take its `LocalDateTime` object. Create a new one by calling `with` and passing `LocalTime.MIN`. Without zone or offset, we know every day and hour is a generic length, 60 minutes, 24 hours.

So loop, adding 15 minutes at a time. Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to define a span-of-time not attached to the timeline, on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( 15 ) ;
```

This gives you a start and stop time.

- If you are adjusting these `LocalDateTime` objects into an offset or time zone, extract a `Instant` for both start and stop. Then contain those as a [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) object, after adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. The `Interval` class offers handy methods for comparison, such as `contains`.
- If using `LocalDateTime`, consider making your own `LocalDateTimeRange` class to hold a pair of `LocalDateTime` objects, and implement a `contains( LocalDateTime )` method.

Your own `LocalDateTimeRange` might look something like this rough-draft completely-untested source code:

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LocalDateTimeRange
{
    final private LocalDateTime start, end;

    public LocalDateTimeRange ( LocalDateTime start , LocalDateTime end )
    {
        this.start = Objects.requireNonNull( start );
        this.end = Objects.requireNonNull( end );
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStart ( )
    {
        return this.start;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEnd ( )
    {
        return this.end;
    }

    public boolean contains ( LocalDateTime ldt )
    {
        // Contains is true if the target is greater-than-or-equal-to (not before) the start, and is less-than (before) the ending. 
        // This approach is known as Half-Open, where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. 
        return ( ! ldt.isBefore( this.getStart() ) ) && ldt.isBefore( this.getEnd() );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        LocalDateTimeRange that = ( LocalDateTimeRange ) o;
        return getStart().equals( that.getStart() ) &&
                getEnd().equals( that.getEnd() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getStart() , getEnd() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return start + "/" + end; // Return string in standard ISO 8601 format. 
    }


    static public LocalDateTimeRange parse ( )
    {
        // Parse a string in standard ISO 8601 format. 
        …
    }
}
```

Compare the object in hand to see if it is not less than the start and is less than the stop. This Half-Open approach to defining a span of time is usually best, where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive.

Continue looping until you find a date-time range that contains the date-time of the object in hand. When found, add to a `Map`, either:

- a `Map < LocalDateTimeRange , < Integer > >` where you increment the count.
- a `Map < LocalDateTimeRange , < List< Event > > >` where you add the `Event` object to the `List` or `Set`.

> if there is no transaction done at that particular time need to populate 0.0

Either add such a value to the map, or leave null the *value* of the map for that `LocalDateRange` *key*.

Loop to next object.

When done, analyze your map.

Tip: Educate the persons publishing that data about:

- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for date-time values serialized as text.
- The importance of always indicating time zone or offset-from-UTC.

All of these topics discussed above have been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more. And search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.